# How to clean alert message from pusher?

Tags: javascript, php, json, alert, pusher

I am using PUSHER into my site for notification.
I successfully added the codes and its working.
But the problem is when the alert is getting triggered I am receiving messages but its not what I am looking for.

I am receiving this message from Javascript alert();

```
{"message":"A new appointment arrived"}
```

[alert message from pusher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtWoe.png)
And my code is

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({url: "notification", success: function(result){
        $("#notification").html(result);
    }})
});
```

And this is where I am getting this.

```
$data['message'] = 'A new appointment arrived';
$pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my-event', $data);
```

I am getting the message from

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

My question is, is there a way I can remove everything except `A new appointment arrived` from the alert message?
Thanks in advance.
I am a beginner and I have very little knowledge about Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you're asking is how you change the output that gets shown in the alert from

```
{"message":"A new appointment arrived"}
```

to just `A new appointment arrived`. Is that right?

What `JSON.stringify()` does is convert a JavaScript object into a string of text in the JSON format. Since you're not actually interested in the object, just the message it contains, there really isn't any need to use `JSON.stringify` here. Assuming that the data you're receiving always has the format

```
{ message: "Some type of message" }
```

you can just write `alert(data.message)` (or `alert(data["message"])` if you don't like JavaScript dot notation).

Comment: Thank you! It worked, `alert(data.message)` but `document.getElementById('audio').play();` it's not working now.

Comment: I don't think I can resolve that issue without seeing the HTML of the page that this is  referencing. Are you sure that an element exists with the ID 'audio'?

Comment: Yes, I have an audio file with this code in that page `<audio id="audio" src="sound/tone.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line: `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` in your JS code. That's triggering the alert with the message received from your Event.

You can read more about `alert()` method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Comment: no no, I want that alert but I want to remove = {"message":" and "} from my message. the alert i'm getting now is = {"message":"A new appointment arrived"}

Comment: I want to remove `curly brackets` also `double quotes` and the word `message` and the `clone`.

Comment: So, in that case, you have to only print the `message` field of your object:
`alert(data.message);`